# Pass Array to Laravel view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-8

```
return view('price')->with('day',$day)->with('values',$values);
```

I tried to pass $day, $values arrays to view.

```
dd($day);
```

gives

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "2021-09-06 18:48:34"
  1 => "2021-09-10 09:59:22"
  2 => "2021-09-28 09:58:02"
]

dd($values)
```

is in similar format.
but when I pass to view (price.blade.php) it says undefined offset[1]

Comment: Show the code from your view (price.blade.php) file where you are using the $values that are passed to it?

Comment: I did not add the variable in view file, there is nothing. just php page. But error is coming when return is called

Comment: Could you add the content of `price.blade.php`? There is nothing in this code that can cause undefined offset 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can chain "with" on views - I think that the second "with" in your code over-writes the first "with", so when you come to use $day in your view, it's not defined.

Where you want to pass multiple variables to a view, rather than :

```
return view('price')->with('day',$day)->with('values',$values);
```

you should use one "with", passing the variables as an array :

```
return view('price')->with(['day' => $day, 'values' => $values]);
```

Where you are giving the variables the same name in the view as they had in the controller, then you can save yourself more time by using the 'compact' function :

```
return view('price')->with(compact('day', 'values');
```

And it will automatically pass through $day as 'day', and $values as 'values'.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: You actually can chain `->with(...)->with(...)`, and the second doesn't override the first, but `->with([...])` or `compact(...)` are definitely cleaner.

Comment: @TimLewis Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return view('price', compact('day', 'values'));
```

Omit the `->with` and make sure that you have declared `$day` and `values`